# Laravel, php artisan migrate:reset cannot drop the table does not exist

Tags: laravel, migrate, laravel-artisan

When I run `php artisan migrate:reset` it throws an error saying:

> Cannot drop the table 'order_user', because it does not exist or you
>   do not have permission.

The table does not exist in my DB. I don't understand why artisan is trying to drop the table. I do have an 'orders' table and a 'users' table. And they have a `belongsToMany` relationship. I do not have a migration for 'order_user'.

Comment: Check the `down` methods in migration classes found in `/database/migrations`. One of them is bound to contain a `Schema::drop('order_user');` expression.

Comment: That was it. I can't believe it. I had changed the name of the table on the up method, but I hadn't changed it on the down method.

Comment: For future reference, if you happen to drop any tables manually (or by any other means) before rolling back migrations, it helps to use the `Schema::dropIfExists('table_name');` method, which does exactly what you'd think, but it doesn't crash the command because of the schema inconsistencies.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. I guess I'm in the awkward phase of becoming a developer where I'm learning the subtle points. Like puberty all over again.

Comment: add a property in the migration class with the table name, use it for both up and down and you'll never miss the second statement ;)